# pdflatex in TexWorks converts .eps files to .pdf upon each compilation, doesn't save them

Tags: pdftex, eps

On Windows, TexWorks (compiling with pdflatex) converts my .eps figures to .pdf each time, not saving the eps-to-pdf files. It makes compilation slow - how can I make it actually "create" the converted files and save them in the directory of my .tex?

Comment: You might use  Siep  Kroonenberg's tool `epspdftk`, which has an installer on Windows, and convert by hand before compiling?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Is this with MiKTeX or TeX Live? What version? Can this be reproduced with one of the EPS files from the [mwe](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package, such as [example-image-a.eps](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-a.eps)? Rename the file after downloading, just to ensure it gets converted, and TeX doesn't find a matching PDF.

Comment: Can you detail your exact setup, in particular are the graphics simply 'here' (in the same folder as the `.tex` file? Can you post a `.log` for a short example?

Comment: pdflatex will call epstopdf which will make the pdf file to be included, it doesn't normally have permissions to delete that file so it should be there next time, unless you have set some script to delete generated files before a latex run.